# Other kinds of jobs or other kind of jobs

Tags: grammar

Which is grammatical:

> Charity work gives tremendous job satisfaction, which wouldn't be compared to other **kinds** of jobs

or:

> Charity work gives tremendous job satisfaction, which wouldn't be compared to other **kind** of jobs

I already know that when you use “other" then it is followed by plural noun: other*people(plural, compoun noun), other books... etc.

Does “other" takes **only** a single noun exactly right after it is used in sentence? Or it can take suceeding plural nouns in a sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You shouldn’t think of “kind” as a separate noun here – think of it as part of a noun phrase.**

Your sentence can be thought of as:

> ...which wouldn't be compared to other **X**

where *X* functions as a plural noun. So, you could write it as:

> ...which wouldn't be compared to other **jobs**

but using a plural noun phrase works fine, too:

> ...which wouldn't be compared to other **types of work**

(In that example, we use the singular *work*, because *work* in that context is a mass noun.)

Getting back to your examples, you need to use the plural form “kinds”:

> ...which wouldn't be compared to other **kinds of jobs**.

You can actually omit the “of jobs”, and see which sentence sounds grammatical:

> ...which wouldn't be compared to other **kinds** → (okay)
> ...which wouldn't be compared to other **kind** → (wrong)

One more interesting fact: you can use a singular noun phrase if you change *other* to *another*:

> ...which wouldn't be compared to **another kind of job**